# Why CardView will adjust position automatically when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout, staggeredgridlayout

I am using RecyclerView and CardView in my project, most parameters of these two widget were default, I haven't customize it much, but two questions came up.

1. Why those CardViews will flash one second when pull down to refresh data which is using SwipeRefreshLayout, can I stop this effect?
2. Why those CardViews will adjust position automatically when scrolling? Can I stop this effect?

The layout I am using for RecyclerView is StaggeredGridLayout, it's inconvenient to post code here beause there too many code in my project to use those widget, so you can tell me which part I should post here, thanks.